# JOIN two columns with same name in diffrent views in postgresql and get the total

Tags: postgresql

I have got this view1

```
    SELECT min(l.id) AS id, 
    to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
    sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, 
    sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, cumulative_balance
    FROM account_move_line l
    LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
    WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text
    GROUP BY to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type;
```

And View2

```
   SELECT min(l.id) AS id, 
   to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
   sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, 
   sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, DATE 'yesterday'
   FROM account_move_line l
   LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
   WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text AND l.date = DATE 'yesterday'
   GROUP BY to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type;
```

view3

```
SELECT min(l.id) AS id, 
to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, 
sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, DATE 'today'
FROM account_move_line l
LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text AND l.date = DATE 'today'
GROUP BY to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type;
```

I want to join column `balance` in view2 and view3 to column `cumulative_balance` in view1 and in this column `cumulative_balance` to be sum of view2.balance and view3.balance

Comment: I failed to comprehend your request. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: I also fail to understand what you're looking for. Perhaps you could give us an example of how you'd like your rows to look.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solutioni finally arrived at, note that view2 and view3 are table t and y and this is view1

```
SELECT yesterday.yesterday, today.today, report.id, report.balance, 
    report.debit, report.credit, cumulative.cumulative, report.name
   FROM ( SELECT y.balance AS yesterday
           FROM report_account_receivable_yesterday) yesterday, 
    ( SELECT t.balance AS today
           FROM report_account_receivable_today) today, 
    ( SELECT sum(y.balance + t.balance) AS cumulative
           FROM report_account_receivable_yesterday y, 
            report_account_receivable_today t) cumulative, 
    ( SELECT min(l.id) AS id, 
            to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
            sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, 
            sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day' AS tarehe
           FROM account_move_line l
      LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
     WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text AND l.date = DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day'
     GROUP BY to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type) report
  ORDER BY report.id DESC;
```

Comment: The Problem now is the DATE i want a date that will be changing everyday not that will stay in one date i.e DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day' should change the next day in the query not stay in the date i queried the statement